# Migration from WebLogic server to wildfly Server

Tags: jms, weblogic-10.x, mq, server-migration, wildfly-21

I have middleware application currently running on WebLogic server and now I need to migrate to Wildfly server. can anyone help how to do this because our application is heavily dependent on WebLogic and we have multiple service to deploy also need to support JMS.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This question is way too broad. You need to be specific about what problems you're having with your migration. Stack Overflow is the place for clear questions with fact-based answers. It's not the place for general tutorials or guides.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.